# ParseUser search

Tags: java, android, xml, parse-platform

I am trying to create a simple user search page for my app. I tried to create a ParseQuery and  display results in a Listview in my main activity page. However, when I run program, I could not get a result of a search, program displays nothing. I will be happy if I get an answer.

Here is my MainActivity.java;

```
package com.example.searchtest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.parse.*;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button search;
    private EditText searchArea;
    private ListView userList;
    private String uName;
    private ArrayAdapter<ParseUser> mainAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Parse.initialize(this, "WHz2GmkGFIUxBir6ZEDt2FIG4WUcE1kfKZmPayxy", "IAs1RCaRt5LM1E1ZW7LFXy5uDjtZEQ5CDa3LKJt2");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
        searchArea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchField);
        userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.results);

        mainAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ParseUser>(this, R.layout.activity_main, R.layout.search_list );
        //mainAdapter.setTextKey("username");

        userList.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
        //mainAdapter.loadObjects();

        uName = searchArea.getText().toString();

        search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
                query.whereEqualTo("username", uName);

                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                  public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        for(int i=0; i<objects.size();i++)
                        {
                            mainAdapter.add((ParseUser)objects.get(i));
                        }

                    } else {
                        // Something went wrong.
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }
                });

                userList.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And my main activity xml file;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.searchtest.MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Search" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. Here is updated version of code;

```
package com.example.searchtest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.parse.*;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button search;
    private EditText searchArea;
    private ListView userList;
    //private String uName;
    private ArrayAdapter<ParseUser> mainAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ParseUser> resultList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Parse.initialize(this, "WHz2GmkGFIUxBir6ZEDt2FIG4WUcE1kfKZmPayxy", "IAs1RCaRt5LM1E1ZW7LFXy5uDjtZEQ5CDa3LKJt2");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
        searchArea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchField);
        userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userResultList);
        resultList = new ArrayList<ParseUser>();
        mainAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ParseUser>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.user_results,resultList);
        //mainAdapter.setTextKey("username");

        //userList.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
        //mainAdapter.loadObjects();



        search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String uName = searchArea.getText().toString();

                final ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
                query.whereEqualTo("username", uName);

                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                  public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {

                           for(int i=0; i<objects.size();i++)
                            {
                                resultList.add((ParseUser)objects.get(i));
                            }
                           userList.setAdapter(mainAdapter);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User is Found",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        // Something went wrong.
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User is not Found",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                  }
                });

                userList.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Moreover I need one more xml file to display the list. it is list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Single ListItem -->

    <!-- Product Name -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/user_results"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

and main xml file, activity_main.xml;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.searchtest.MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Search" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/userResultList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/searchField"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchField"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

put uName = searchArea.getText().toString(); inside the listener, you are setting uName only once when the view is created, so it will be empty. You need to get the text after the user enters input and the button is clicked.

Comment: nothing is changed. I still can't get a result of a search.

Comment: Do you get an exception in the callback? Did you print the value of `uName` to confirm you pass in the right data? Did you check the list's size in the callback? Do you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after you update your `Adapter`.

Comment: Step through a debug and check the values of uName and the query.